# Using BeautifulSoup to scrape a specific website

Tags: html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

Hi StackExchange Community!

I'm trying to run a code that would scrape the following website: http://apps.mmc.gov.my/searchmmc/main_search.php?action=detail&id=10000

Into a dataset which consist of the name, qualification, undergraduate degree, provisional registration number, as well as the Places of Practice underneath.

I've been struggling for a bit the last couple of days, due to the way the website is structured:

```html
-->
  </style>
  <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type"/>
  <title>
   :: MEDICAL REGISTER (MMC) ::
  </title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <table border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0" width="620">
   <tr class="f10px-table-caption" valign="bottom">
    <th colspan="3">
     <table border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0">
      <tr class="f10px-table-caption" valign="bottom">
       <th align="left" class="f10px-table-caption" scope="col" width="25%">
        NAME
       </th>
       <th class="f10px-table-caption" scope="col" width="5%">
        :
       </th>
       <th align="left" class="f10px-table-caption" scope="col" width="70%">
        JAPAR B ZAIRUN
       </th>
       <th rowspan="7">
        <img height="140" src="showusrimg.php?PP_id=10000" width="100"/>
       </th>
      </tr>
      <tr class="f10px-table-caption" valign="bottom">
       <th align="left" class="f10px-table-caption" scope="col" width="25%">
        QUALIFICATION
       </th>
       <th class="f10px-table-caption" scope="col" width="5%">
        :
       </th>
       <th align="left" class="f10px-table-caption" scope="col" width="70%">
        MD
       </th>
      </tr>
      <tr class="f10px-table-caption" valign="bottom">
       <th align="left" class="f10px-table-caption" scope="col" valign="top" width="25%">
        UNDERGRADUATE OF
       </th>
       <th class="f10px-table-caption" scope="col" valign="top" width="5%">
        :
       </th>
       <th align="left" class="f10px-table-caption" scope="col" valign="top" width="70%">
        UNIVERSITI KEBANGSAAN MALAYSIA (UKM)
       </th>
      </tr>
      <tr class="f10px-table-caption" valign="bottom">
       <th align="left" class="f10px-table-caption" scope="col">
        PROVISIONAL
        <br/>
        REGISTRATION NUMBER
       </th>
       <th class="f10px-table-caption" scope="col">
        :
       </th>
       <th align="left" class="f10px-table-caption" scope="col">
        20159
       </th>
      </tr>
      <tr class="f10px-table-caption" valign="bottom">
       <th align="left" class="f10px-table-caption" scope="col" width="25%">
        DATE OF
        <br/>
        PROVISIONAL REGISTRATION
       </th>
       <th class="f10px-table-caption" scope="col" width="25%">
        :
       </th>
       <th align="left" class="f10px-table-caption" scope="col" width="5%">
        --
       </th>
      </tr>
      <tr class="f10px-table-caption" valign="bottom">
       <th align="left" class="f10px-table-caption" scope="col" width="25%">
        FULL
        <br/>
        REGISTRATION NUMBER
       </th>
       <th class="f10px-table-caption" scope="col" width="5%">
        :
       </th>
       <th align="left" class="f10px-table-caption" colspan="2" scope="col" width="70%">
        31398
       </th>
      </tr>
      <tr class="f10px-table-caption" valign="bottom">
       <th align="left" class="f10px-table-caption" scope="col" width="25%">
        DATE OF
        <br/>
        FULL REGISTRATION
       </th>
       <th class="f10px-table-caption" scope="col" width="5%">
        :
       </th>
       <th align="left" class="f10px-table-caption" colspan="2" scope="col" width="70%">
        16-06-1995
       </th>
      </tr>
     </table>
    </th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <th bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="f10px" scope="col">
    </th>
    <th bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="f10px" scope="col">
    </th>
    <th bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="f10px" scope="col">
    </th>
   </tr>
   <tr class="f10px-table-caption" valign="bottom">
    <th align="left" class="f10px-table-caption" colspan="3" scope="col">
     *
    </th>
   </tr>
   <tr class="f10px-table-caption" valign="bottom">
    <th bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="f10px-table-caption" colspan="3" scope="col">
     <br/>
    </th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <th bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="f10px-table-caption" colspan="3" scope="col">
     <table align="center" border="1" bordercolor="#000000" bordercolordark="#000000" bordercolorlight="#000000" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
      <tr bgcolor="#BDE3F9" class="f10px-table-header">
       <th align="center" colspan="5">
        APC
       </th>
      </tr>
      <tr bgcolor="#BDE3F9" class="f10px-table-header">
       <th align="center" width="4%">
        #
       </th>
       <th align="center" width="10%">
        APC YEAR
       </th>
       <th align="center" width="10%">
        APC NO
       </th>
       <th align="left" width="38%">
        PLACE OF PRACTICE (PRINCIPAL)
       </th>
       <th align="left" width="38%">
        PLACE OF PRACTICE (OTHERS)
       </th>
      </tr>
      <tr class="f10px-table-caption">
       <td align="center">
        1.
       </td>
       <td align="center">
        2017
       </td>
       <td align="center">
        15463
       </td>
       <td>
        KLINIK ELOPURA SDN BHD
        <br/>
        NO. 31, GF, 2ND AVENUE
        <br/>
        90000 SANDAKAN
        <br/>
        SABAH
       </td>
       <td>
       </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="f10px-table-caption">
       <td align="center">
        2.
       </td>
       <td align="center">
        2016
       </td>
       <td align="center">
        13154
       </td>
       <td>
        KLINIK ELOPURA SDN BHD
        <br/>
        NO. 31, GF, 2ND AVENUE
        <br/>
        90000 SANDAKAN
        <br/>
        SABAH
       </td>
       <td>
       </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="f10px-table-caption">
       <td align="center">
        3.
       </td>
       <td align="center">
        2015
       </td>
       <td align="center">
        10501
       </td>
       <td>
        KLINIK ELOPURA SDN BHD
        <br/>
        NO. 31, GF, 2ND AVENUE
        <br/>
        90000 SANDAKAN
        <br/>
        SABAH
       </td>
       <td>
       </td>
      </tr>
     </table>
    </th>
   </tr>
   <th bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="f10px-table-caption" colspan="3" scope="col">
    Only the latest 3 years of the APC will be displayed as decided by the Council Members during the MMC meeting held on 12th July 2011.
   </th>
  </table>
  <p>
   <strong>
   </strong>
  </p>
  <script language="javascript">
   function GotoPage(pageno){
 
 //obj=document.all.item("clue");
 //obj2=document.all.item("cboSearch");
 //obj2.value=obj.value;
 
 obj=document.forms["searchuser"];
 obj.action="main_search.php?action=search&page=" + pageno;
 obj.submit();
}

function ShowDetails(id_pp){
 win=window.open("main_search.php?action=detail&id=" + id_pp);
 win.focus();
 /*obj.action="main_search.php?action=detail&id=" + id_pp;
 obj.submit();*/
}
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

If I can figure out how to extract the name and qualification in a structured manner, that would be a tremendous achievement in itself.

Thank you so much for taking the time for reading my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import requests, bs4

r = requests.get('http://apps.mmc.gov.my/searchmmc/main_search.php?action=detail&id=10000')
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
for tr in soup.select('tr table tr[valign="bottom"]'):
    print(tr.get_text(strip=True))
```

out:

```
NAME:JAPAR B ZAIRUN
QUALIFICATION:MD
UNDERGRADUATE OF:UNIVERSITI KEBANGSAAN MALAYSIA (UKM)
PROVISIONALREGISTRATION NUMBER:20159
DATE OFPROVISIONAL REGISTRATION:--
FULLREGISTRATION NUMBER:31398
DATE OFFULL REGISTRATION:16-06-1995
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Just a follow up question, how would you loop through the id=10000 part from 1 to 100 i.e

for i in range(100):
    url = "http://apps.mmc.gov.my/searchmmc/main_search.php?action=detail&id={}".format(i)

and extracting the NAME: content as a column in a dataset? 

Thank you so much.